# Hide project activity in gitlab dashboard for specific projects

Tags: git, gitlab

I was added to a new project but just to see the code, and now I am starting to see every commit in my dashboard and it is polluting my entire dashboard.. Is there any way so that I can hide the project activity and just see the ones I want in the dashboard?

Comment: And consider upvoting the feedback ideas VonC linked to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ability to filter a project activity is already suggested (but not implemented yet) in:

- [Feature proposal: ignore project (hide project activity)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/299531)

There is no subscription mechanism yet.

---

Somewhat related in [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#toggle-metrics-dashboards-visibility)

> ### Toggle Metrics Dashboards visibility
>
> Previously, project administrators couldn’t control permission to view a project’s metrics dashboards.
>
> **As part of GitLab 13.0, admins can now toggle metric dashboard visibility to either project members, or to everyone with access**.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_0/Dashboard_visability.png]

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/prometheus.html#metrics-dashboard-visibility) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/201924).

Comment: These links seem to be broken and I cannot find where they moved to. Anyone knows what happened to feedback.gitlab.com?

Comment: @MakisH Certificate issue, I presume... https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/2732